# Copy a file in java program that runs on unix platform

Tags: java, file, unix

We can do this in different ways but got a question what is the best on from below

1. Using Outputstream
2. Invoking a CP command to run as a process

Please let me know what you will opt for?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 7, you can use one of the `Files.copy()` methods available there.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use java for that.
If you use it then it is better to use `OutputStream` - it means less dependencies for the program and it will use only a single process instead of two (one for java and one for `cp`).

Comment: Yeah, 2 process may not be a good idea. It makes sense. I just thinking this stupid way because to avoid few line of code to be written to open, read and close these streams. And fact, I have a good utilities ready available to work with commands.